# Testing for mediation using LMER and a Freedman and Schatzkin's method (in R)

Tags: r, mixed-model, lme4-nlme, mediation

I'm trying to analyse, whether the effect of answer correctness ($X$, binary) on confidence ratings ($Y$, continuous) in some psychological task is mediated by another rating ($M$, continuous). In order to do so I created two LMER models (I use LMER to account for random effect for stimuli and subjects), `Y~X` and `Y~X+M`. I'm trying to use a Freedman and Schatzkin's approach, as described in [MacKinnon et al. (2002)](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2819363/), to test, whether the addition of mediator significantly changed the coefficient for $X\rightarrow Y$.

So, here is my first question: **is it OK to use this approach with LMER?**

My second question is, **am I doing it correctly?** Here is the code I use (`fit.conf2` and `fit.conf3` are models with and without mediator):

```
coef1<-coef(summary(fit.conf2))

            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)   3.2497     6.8845   0.472
X            14.6572     1.7978   8.153
Z             0.9881     0.1289   7.668

coef2<-coef(summary(fit.conf3))

            Estimate Std. Error t value
(Intercept)  -6.5571    6.23014  -1.052
X            11.7775    1.61874   7.276
Z             0.7228    0.11947   6.050
M             0.4908    0.02968  16.536

t<-coef1[2,1]
tprim<-coef2[2,1]
st<-coef1[2,2]
stprim<-coef2[2,2]
corxm<-cor(M, X)

sigmaFS = sqrt(st^2+stprim^2-2*st*stprim*sqrt(1-corxm^2))

[1] 0.4411

tFS = (t-tprim)/sigmaFS

[1] 6.529

dFS = length(Y)-3
pFS = (1 - pt(tFS, dFS))*2
```

I am especially concerned about whether I am using correct df. Please, correct me if I am doing something stupid here.